# Power analysis for Generalized Linear Model with gamma family and log link in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, statistical-power, glmm, effect-size

I have a data set with 360 observations. I run a glm with a gamma family, and I want to show that I fail to reject the null hypothesis. Although the p-value greater than 0.05 is kind of showing that but I was asked to report the power of my test. I wonder if it is right to use cohen's d for multiple regression (f-test), as my DV (nor my residuals) is not normally distributed. I can see lots of packages in R like lme4 and Simr for calculating the power of Generalized Linear Mixed Model, but they do not cover glm. Does anybody have a suggestion for my case? How should I calculate such a statistical test's effect size and power?